# Is there a preferred type for an Observable with no need for a value in Next events?

Tags: swift, rx-swift, reactivex

I have an Observable which is only used for triggering `flatMap`/`map`.  So I only ever need the `Next` event and never a value.  I could use my own concept for such a trash value, but I'm wondering if there's an RxSwift convention for it.

Here's what I'm dealing with:

```
// I'd rather not have an Element type that someone might use
let triggeringObservable: Observable<SomeSessionClass> 

// ...

triggeringObservable.map { _ -> String in // The actual value is ignored
    return SomeLibrary.username() // `username()` is only ready when `triggeringObservable` sends Next
}
```

In this example, `triggeringObservable` is `rx_observer` on some property in the library which will let us know that `username()` is ready to be called.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

You can simply use an `Observable<Void>` for this purpose. Like so:

```
   let triggerObservable = Observable<Void>.just()

    triggerObservable.subscribeNext() {
        debugPrint("received notification!")
    }.addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```

or in your example:

```
let triggeringObservable: Observable<Void> 

// ...

triggeringObservable.map { Void -> String in // The actual value is ignored
   return SomeLibrary.username() 
}
```

Answer (score 9):

In Swift 4 (and probably earlier) you can pass an empty tuple as an argument to a method expecting a Void associated type.

```
var triggerObservable = PublishSubject<Void>()
...
triggerObservable.onNext(()) // "()" empty tuple is accepted for a Void argument
```

Or you can define an extension to overload onNext() with no args for the Void case:

```
extension ObserverType where E == Void {
    public func onNext() {
        onNext(())
    }
}

...
triggerObservable.onNext()
```

Comment: In Swift 5.1, I had to explicitly pass a Void() to onNext(). Cheers.

Comment: Your solution enables multiple events with one subsrciption. The ones with Just are single use only. +1

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on Swift 4.1:

```
Observable<Void>.just(Void())
```

Answer (score 6):

This worked for me on Swift 4.2:

```
Observable<Void>.just(())
```

Answer (score 0):

With swift 4, Xcode will say you cannot invoke 'just' with no arguments. we're currently using following workaround:

```
    Observable.just(Void.self).subscribe(onNext: { Void -> String in
        debugPrint("triggered!")
    }).addDisposableTo(disposeBag)
```